# All my Angular Controllers are becoming an instance of same controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this markup which calls two directives:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <accordion-controls></accordion-controls>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <wysiwyg-display></wysiwyg-display>
    </div>
</div>
```

module is declared like this:

```
var BuilderModule = angular
   .module(ModuleName, [])
   .controller('builderWysiwygController', BuilderWysiwygController)
   .controller("builderAccordionController", BuilderAccordionController)
   .directive("wysiwygDisplay", () => new WysiwygDisplayDirective())
   .directive("accordionControls", () => new AccordionControlsDirective())
   .service("builderService", BuilderService);
```

the accordion-controls component looks like this:

```
export class AccordionControlsDirective {
   constructor() {
      this.templateUrl = 'app/builder/builder-accordion.html';
      this.restrict = 'E';
      this.controller = "builderAccordionController";
      this.controllerAs = "ctrl";
   }

   link(scope, ele, attrs) {
      //
   }
}

export class BuilderAccordionController {
   constructor(builderService) {
      this.builderService = builderService;
      this.currentMenuModel = this.builderService.currentMenuModel;
      this.templates = this.builderService.templates;
      this.headlines = this.builderService.lists.Headlines;
      this.accordionForm;

      this.builderService.init().then(() => {
         let buns = this.builderService.getDefaultBuns();
         this.templates = this.builderService.getTemplates();
         this.headlines = this.builderService.getHeadlines();
      });
   }
}
```

the wysiwyg directive looks like this:

```
export class WysiwygDisplayDirective {
   constructor() {
      this.templateUrl = 'app/builder/builder-wysiwyg.html';
      this.restrict = 'E';
      this.controller = "builderWysiwygController";
      this.controllerAs = "ctrl";
   }

   link(scope, ele, attrs) {
      //
   }
}

export class BuilderWysiwygController {
   constructor(builderService) {
      this.builderService = builderService;
      this.currentMenuModel = this.builderService.currentMenuModel;
   }
}
```

However, when I load the page, the markup that is part of the accordion-controls directive has a controller of BuilderWysiwygController instead of BuilderAccordionController.

Here is a screenshot of the Chrome dev tools showing a select element that is part of the accordion-controls directive, but having a controller of "BuilderWysiwygController"

[image]

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I don't seem able to see it. Why is my accordion-controls directive getting the wrong controller attached to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directives miss `scope` properties, which means that both of them are compiled against parent scope.

The controllers may be different (and they are), but since controllerAs identifier is the same for both, `ctrl` scope property will be overwritten by the last compiled directive (which is `wysiwygDisplay`).